# Cypress - XML response parsing of XHR request using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, cypress

I have a Cypress test which fires an XHR request, which is returning XML response. My objective is to parse the XML response and validate few nodes. I used JQuery - `parseXML()`, which is working as expected; but, when I try to iterate the parsed XMLs, I face some the below error,

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

which I suspect at the line -> `Cypress.$(java).each(function()`

**Cypress test:**

```
 it("cy.request - make an XHR request", () => {
    cy.request({
        log: true,
        url: "SOME_URL",
        auth: {
            user: Cypress.env('userName'),
            pass: Cypress.env('password')
        }
    }).then(response => {
            const xml = Cypress.$.parseXML(response.body)
            cy.log(response.body)
            console.log(xml)
            const java = xml.getElementsByTagName('java')
            Cypress.$(java).each(function() {
                cy.log($(this).find("configuration>property>name").text())
            })
            expect(response).property("status").to.equal(200);
        });
    });
```

**Sample XML response:**

```
<workflow-app name="Samyghjggjg" xmlns="hjkh">
    <action name="etl-69b5" retry-max="0" retry-interval="10">
        <java>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name1</name>
                </property>
            </configuration>
        </java>
        <java>
            <configuration>
                <property>
                    <name>mapred.job.queue.name2</name>
                </property>
            </configuration>
        </java>
    </action>
</workflow-app>
```

Did some analysis and noted the below details from - https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/$.html#Syntax

> Calling Cypress.$('button') will automatically query for elements in your remote window. In other words, Cypress automatically sets the document to be whatever you’ve currently navigated to via cy.visit().

Any help would be appreciated to overcome this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that inside the `cy.log($(this)....` you might still need to add `cy.log(Cypress.$(this)...` in order to use the `jquery` in Cypress. I haven't tried yet,  but its worth to give a try.

```
Cypress.$(java).each(function() {
            cy.log(Cypress.$(this).find("configuration>property>name").text())
        })
```